# R plm: understand pmodel.response

Tags: r, prediction, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, plm

I need help in understanding the `pmodel.response` function from the R package `plm`. So far I have interpreted this as a way to get predicted values from a panel data regression.

In the code below I run a least squares dummy variables regression using the standard `lm`-function and a fixed effects model using `plm` and then try to compare predictions and model response.

```
library(plm)

data(Grunfeld)
Grunfeld <- pdata.frame(Grunfeld, index = c("firm", "year"))

grun.lm <- lm(inv ~ value + capital + factor(firm), data=Grunfeld)
grun.fe <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, data=Grunfeld, effect="individual",
               model="within")

Grunfeld$predict.lm <- predict(grun.lm)
Grunfeld$predict.plm <- pmodel.response(grun.fe)
```

Now, if I take a look at the outcome:

```
> head(Grunfeld)
       firm year   inv  value capital predict.lm predict.plm
1-1935    1 1935 317.6 3078.5     2.8   269.5876     -290.42
1-1936    1 1936 391.8 4661.7    52.6   459.3769     -216.22
1-1937    1 1937 410.6 5387.1   156.9   571.6005     -197.42
1-1938    1 1938 257.7 2792.2   209.2   302.0566     -350.32
1-1939    1 1939 330.8 4313.2   203.4   467.7566     -277.22
1-1940    1 1940 461.2 4643.9   207.2   505.3528     -146.82
```

It seems like the output of `pmodel.response` hardly has anything to do with predicted values. So, what does this function actually do? How to interpret the values in column `Grundfeld$predict.plm`? This does not get clear for me from the documentation.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I also was interested in knowing the answer but after playing with the function i've realized that it produces predicted (transformed) values. since you're using "within" transformation, the pmodel.response output are the predicted demeaned values.

Comment: Yes. The help page of `pmodel.response` says exactly that: "pmodel.response has several methods to conveniently extract the response of several objects." Since lots of panel models do some sort of transformation before the regression, this is a convenience function to get these transformations.

Comment: @ Sarunas: delete "predicted" in your answer and put "transformed" in there. `pmodel.matrix` is about the transformations for the various model types (like @mpiktas) explained.